# Simple PHP echo code not working

Tags: php, echo

Here is my html with a php script:

> ```
>   <html>
>       <head>
>     <title>Bob's Auto Parts</title>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <h1>Bob's Auto Parts</h1>
>      <table width = 100% >
>          <tr>
>              <?php
>                  echo "<td>This is working.</td>";
>              ?>
>          </tr>
>      </table>
>   </body>
>  </html>
> ```

Why is the output of this appearing with a ; ?>. I want it to be 'This is working.' only. Here is the ouput

> Bob's Auto Parts
>
> ## Bob's Auto Parts
>
> This is working.";
>                    ?>

I know I am doing something wrong here but not able to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should work. Do you by some chance have short PHP tags on? This can somehow be triggering the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you try to reproduce it on this site and link it here? http://codepad.viper-7.com/
Additionally, what you're doing inside the `table` tag is bad. Instead, do this: `<table style="width: 100%">`

Comment: If you could include the full output of the file, that would help greatly.

Comment: Is it a .php file? Are you running php on your server? Have you tried `print()` or any other output methods?

Comment: Do you have PHP installed on the server?

Comment: How? I can't see short tags being an issue here.

Comment: Short tags would not cause this problem.

Comment: Reformatted. Sorry, this is first time on stackoverflow and early days with html and php...

Comment: Yes. I have PHP installed. It is not on the server but on my mac.

Comment: Not tried print() or any other output. I started with a bigger script and trimmed it down to this one statement. Let me try with print

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Any of these (or more) could be your answer why it is not working

1. Is there actually PHP running on your computer?
2. Is the file extension `.php`?
3. Are you accesing the file through your browser doing something like `http://localhost/myfile.php`
4. If it is on a remote server, is there PHP installed?

Comment: - Yes. PHP is running on my computer. I have run other PHP file successfully.

Comment: - The file extension was php. But that did not work. So i renamed it to html and then tried. It worked but with this output.

Comment: you should put .php back, .html is not for php

Comment: Thanks. That made it work. Not sure why it was not working earlier when it was .php. At that point Firefox was bringing up the open/save dialog for the .php file. I will now try to implement the full script and see how it behaves. Thanks for the fix though.

Comment: How would one check id php was running? Would it show up on task manager? Also, why does it matter if the file is accessed like that?

Comment: I have done all the points you mentions but still I am having the same error. @Rene Pot

Answer (score 34):

Make sure that you are using `<?php` and not `<?` shorthand since that may be disabled on your server. This will cause the output of "; ?> as it happened to me a few months ago in a transition to PHP5.

I've only seen the odd output like this when the PHP parser isn't detecting it as PHP. Make sure to check that PHP is functioning as expected and that the `<?php` tag is being recognized.

Answer (score 10):

In my case (which is a very specific case) installing this missing package (Ubuntu 14.04) did the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

for users working with php7 install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

After that, just restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And there you go.

Comment: Similarly, going from 14.04 to 16.04, they changed the version of PHP to 7 and I had to install it by hand!

Comment: For Linux Mint Cinnamon (serena) edition 18.0, second step  install libapache2-mod-php7.0 will fix the issue. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I figured out my mistake:

Instead of correct `http://localhost/test.php` I just double clicked on the file `file:///C:/Users/.../htdocs/test.php`.

Answer (score 1):

The file was being saved in UniCode Encoding. Opened the file in Notepad, and saved by changing the Encoding to "ANSI" and saved the file as fileName.php and type "All Files", Encoding as "ANSI".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the extension is .php
and check echo tags on phpmanual.
php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

When you try to include html tags inside echo function, you need to insert between "" or '' and use . between elements.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display PHP, or run embededded PHP, you need to tell PHP to look inside the HTM & HTML files.

You need to have a file in the root folder of the HTML directory called `.htaccess`, which is a simple text file, with the following line:

`#AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`

This lets the PHP compiler know to compile the php when displaying the HTML page.

Comment: Apache 2.2 httpd.conf   AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml .html .htm

Comment: @JonGoodwin thanks, worked for me in apache config file. htacess did not

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost/demo/demo.html will not work.
http://localhost/demo/demo.php will work.
php work on .php extension.
Good Luck bro

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed more than 2 versions of PHP. The server may get confused sometime regarding this. First uninstall the php versions and reinstall only one PHP version.