# phpinfo() is working and echo is not - Why would this be?

Tags: echo, php

Obviously I was looking to do something else but as it wasnt working, I have stepped back to a very fundamental test:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

```
<?php
    echo "Test";
?>
```

Can anybody give me any ideas as to why the first script works, and the second doesnt. Nothing else in the file, just one or the other! A .php extension.

Not sure why I am having to iterate over this - thanks alot phaberest!
The resolution in the suggested duplication talked about having a php file extension - well this has a php file extension. On the other points that @rene pot, put forward - phpinfo() is outputting, so yes there is php installed on the server. I am not using localhost but servername.co.uk/phpinfo.php

Comment: that should be working properly, what output do u get with phpinfo() ?

Comment: Normal output - whitesceen on the echo

Comment: it  working fine . run file and find 'Test' . it's page end display . check

Comment: Have you tried following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639271/simple-php-echo-code-not-working instructions?

Comment: have you tried, for example to call some function or something else? does it work?

Comment: what is your file extension ?? It should .php .

Comment: Similar problem: [phpinfo() works, but nothing else](http://forums.iis.net/t/1166931.aspx?phpinfo+works+but+nothing+else+)

Comment: @AndrewSeabrook If you remove `<?php` tags from the file and keep only the text there, will it work?

Comment: Well started off wanting to get the apache version using $version = apache_get_version();
echo "$version\n"; this was either before or after the phpinfo(); statement - whitescreen - so lost the apache and just added the echo  - but again whitescreen - dump phpinfo(); white screen  - phpinfo() seems working in isolation only!

Comment: @AndrewSeabrook Anything in the error log?

Comment: "Test" alone without php tags works fine! Apache error log? Dont have access to it!

Comment: Is your phpinfo() is disabled in php.ini

Comment: What about `<?PHP echo "Test"; phpinfo(); ?>` and file is saved in plaintext?

Comment: phpinfo(); is working fine - the problem is that other php statements are not working.

Comment: What is the returned status code? Is it 200 (OK)?

Comment: @bobblebubble I did this already - it whitesceens if echo or other php command  is in the script with phpinfo()

Comment: @Philipe how do I see the return status?

Comment: @AndrewSeabrook if you are using Chrome or Firefox you can press F12 and see the status code in the network tab.

Comment: Have you checked any error logs? Have you had a look at the *raw* return from the server (meaning View Source in the browser)?

Comment: @Philipe Aha - 500 Internal Server Error so obviously something not right!

Comment: @deceze view source is blank - which error logs. I have no access to Apache.

Comment: A 500 error without access to error logs is quite unproductive... We could be poking into the dark all day with this...

Comment: @Philipe Thanks for the tip about network return status - didnt know I had access to that.

Comment: @deceze Yes internal pollitics here - giving me a load of grief! Any other suggestions?

Comment: `<?PHP error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); echo "foo"; ?>` also blank right?

Comment: @bobblebubble indeed blank!

Comment: I agree with @deceze, without error logging this is going to be difficult. Can you try to create a file with different name and put the echo in it? Do you have a `.htaccess` file in the directory?

Comment: @Philipe new file test.php containing <?php echo "test"; ?> same whitescreen. There doesnt appear to be an .htaccess file there - but this is surprising as it is a wordpress root directory. Jumping through hoops though, as I dont have ftp access either - using a wp file manager plugin to access the directory and upload files etc. Beginning to think its time to get out the soap and wash my hands.

Comment: Are you trying to do the `<?php echo "Test"; ?>` in the same `phpinfo.php` file? Or in a different file? If different, try doint the echo test in the same file with same filename.

Comment: This might be far out .. but what about CHMOD ? .. Do you have read permission (755) for the folder ?

Comment: @nl-x yes Its has been the same file but tried in a test.php as well.

Comment: @DTH Well I am not able to see a chmod number, but a stylised permission statement in this filemanger toy tells me I have Read and Write permissions.

Comment: Probably plucking at straws but is there any bearing on the problem.I had assumed that the server was apache which I may have inadervertantly suggested when someone above asked about logs, but it is IIS - of which I have no prior knowledge at all?

Comment: @AndrewSeabrook were you able to figure what the issue is?

Comment: @dchayka sorry mate I have a feeling this is going to be one that escapes! I still dont have an answer.

Comment: This is evidently a server configuration problem, likely due to permissions or security restrictions placed by the server host. Without access to the error logs, I believe there's nothing much anyone can do to help. If you list the hosting platform, OS, webserver versions and any related server environment-related info, perhaps we can better coordinate and focus the stabs in the dark towards a general direction.